# How to seal cracks between stone veneer and soffit?

Tags: exterior, sealing

My home is wooden stud construction with rough limestone block veneer.  I have lots of gaps that have opened up where the top of the veneer meets the soffit.  It looks like these gaps were originally closed with mortar or a similar material.

Image attached is an example and show some small cracking.  In some areas the gap is up to an inch wide where this brittle material is breaking away.

What is the best way to repair this?  Caulk?  If so, what type?  Or does a similar mortar type material need to be used?

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a long lasting repair, I'd suggest a gunnable rubberized/polyurethane caulk such as Sonolastic NP1. It comes in various colors. Depending on your locating, there MAY be a home improvement store, Lowe's and/or Home Depot specifically, that stocks it. If you don't have either around, you'll need to check with a roofing supply house.

Comment: Urethane caulks are fairly readily available these days. They truly are the best of the common options, but BEWARE, once that stuff touches something it's not coming off. Protect skin, clothes, etc.

Comment: how about using the silicone sealant or polyurethane sealant to filling the gap,
which is easy to apply